# IBM-Bluemix Push Service build for iOS Simulator fails

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm trying to build my Cordova-app that's using the IBM-Push Service for the iOS Simulator.
It fails with the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IMFPushClient", referenced from:
      _globalinit_33_39105BEEF401CB604E77C276DFBC7CAA_func0 in CDVMFPPush.o
      myApp.CDVMFPPush.__allocating_init () -> myApp.CDVMFPPush in CDVMFPPush.o
      myApp.CDVMFPPush.__allocating_init (webView : __ObjC.UIWebView!) -> myApp.CDVMFPPush! in CDVMFPPush.o
      myApp.CDVMFPPush.init () -> myApp.CDVMFPPush in CDVMFPPush.o
      @objc myApp.CDVMFPPush.init () -> myApp.CDVMFPPush in CDVMFPPush.o
      function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed> of myApp.CDVMFPPush.init (webView : __ObjC.UIWebView!) -> myApp.CDVMFPPush! in CDVMFPPush.o
      l_get_field_types_CDVMFPPush in CDVMFPPush.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I build the app for a real device, it works without problems.

I am aware that Push Notifications aren't working on the simulator, but I need to take screenshots for the upload to the App Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push Notifications will only work on an actual device for iOS.

I would advise connecting your iOS app to your Mac and using Quicktime to capture your screen.

[Here is a CNET article about this feature](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-record-your-iphones-screen-and-audio-using-a-mac/).

Let me know if this will work for you.

Comment: Taking screenshots on an actual device is no problem (using XCode you can directly access the device for the screenshots). But I don't have all the real devices I need screenshots for (4.7" for example). Thus, using the simulator would be perfect. And - as mentioned - I'm aware that Push Notifications aren't working on the simulator, but that's not a problem, since I need screenshots from other parts of the app.

Comment: I know you could probably comment out the Push code and run it in the simulator without issues, but let me speak with the dev team to see if you have any other options.

Comment: I followed up with the dev team, and they had the same solution. Either capture the screen and perform some photoshop for the different devices, or comment out the Push code.